# Proxy property isn't working in package.json

Tags: reactjs, fetch, package.json

I'm new to react, I'm trying to make post request to an API endpoint. I sat the proxy in package.json to the endpoint url and here is the fetch function:

```
const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
    password: password,
  }),
};

const res = await fetch("/token", requestOptions);
```

and here is my proxy prop: `"proxy": "https://somedomain/api/auth"`

when I do `console.log(res.url)`, It always print "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/token/"
not "https://somedomain/api/auth/token/"

why is that ?

And is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `Accept` header, which is currently missing. Headers would look as follows:

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json"
}
```

Other ways to proxy

1. You can download the `http-proxy-middleware` package and configure your proxy.
2. You could use [webpack proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) and send your request to a different end server.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
  }
};
```

NOTE: Keep in mind the CORS issues would pop up so add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header as well.